# driver.findElement(By.id( string value and click

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
String button_name = "user-name";
driver.findElement(By.id("button_name")).click();
```

I have fall into above situation where i need to find and click id which is there in string `driver.findElement(By.id(STRING)).click`. 
Please help me out how to write my snippet.

Answer (score 1):

```
string button_name = "user-name";
driver.findElement(By.id(button_name)).click();
```

Works fine for me.